# How to use a jinja varible (List of Strings) passed from flask in document.getelementbyId().innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

I'm passing a variable 'msg', which is a list of strings, from flask to a page. When I try to use the variable in Document.getelementbyID.innerhtml it's not working.

```
return jsonify({'data':render_template('chart.html', cor=cor, legend=legend, msg = msg)})
```

```
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = {{msg[0]}};
```

'msg' is a list of strings:

```
msg = ['Sucess', 'Sucess', 'Failed', 'Failed', 'Sucess']
```

Can someone help me how to Display the contents of the jinja variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap variable interpolation in quotes so that it is valid JS string.

`document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "{{ msg[0] }}";`